# Navagraham in Vishnu temples

Tags: vishnu, temple, vaishnavism, navagraha

In many Vishnu or Vaishnavism temples, the Navagraham deities are not installed. You may find them in some temples, but in at least 70% of Vishnu temples, you would not.

Is there a specific reason behind this?  I am aware that Sri Vaishnavism, Narayanan is considered the ultimate saviour, but is it the only reason for the Navagrahams to lose their place?

Comment: Yeah, it's just a consequence of the fact that some Sri Vaishnavas don't believe in worshipping gods other than Vishnu (or not directly related to Vishnu).  Like some Sri Vaishnava temples won't even have a Ganesha statue at the entrance; instead they'll either have a statue of Vishvaksena (whom Ganesha is considered an incarnation of) or a statue of "Tumbikai Alwar", a Vaishnava equivalent of Ganesha.

Comment: By the way, I just posted a question about the Sri Vaishnava beliefs concerning Tumbikai Alwar here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7160/36