# What is known about the Kaustubh Mani that came out of the Samudra Manthana?

Tags: vishnu, samudra-manthan

What is known about the Kaustubh Mani that came out of the Samudra Manthana?

This wiki article says that the gem is [worn by Vishnu.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaustubha)

Are there any texts which go into more details?

Comment: The Tamil Vaishnava poet-saint Kulasekhara Alwar, who was the emperor of the Chera Empire, was an incarnation of Vishnu's Kaustubha gem; see my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7838/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yup, I have read that question, any references?

Answer (score 3):

The Word "Kausthubha"  is a combination of two  words,
 Kausa+Abha(कौस्थ+अभा).Abha means Light or Grace , Luster , Brightness etc.

> सशंख चक्रं सकिरीत कुण्डलं, 
>   सपीत वस्त्रं सर्सि रुहेक्षनं । 
>  
>   सहार **वक्षस्थल कौस्तुभश्रियं**,
>   नमामि विष्णुं शिरसा चतुर्भुजं ।।
>
> sashankha chakraM sakiriita kuNDalaM, sapiita vastraM sarsi
>   ruhekshanaM sahaar **vakshasthala kaustubhashriyaM,** namaami viShNuM
>   shirsaa chaturbhujaM [**Vishnu Stuti**](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_vishnu-sashankhachakram.php)

We find mentioning of Kausthubha Mani in various places in puranas.

> **कौस्तुभाख्यमभूद्** रत्नं पद्मरागो महोदधे:।
>  तस्मिन्हरी: स्पृहं चक्रे वक्षोsलङ्करणे मणौ॥५॥
>
> **kaustubhākhyam abhūd** ratnaṁ  padmarāgo mahodadheḥ tasmin maṇau spṛhāṁ cakre  vakṣo-’laṅkaraṇe hariḥ
>
> Meaning- Generated thereafter from the great ocean were the celebrated
>   gems **Kaustubha-maṇi** and Padmarāga-maṇi. **Lord Viṣṇu, to decorate His
>   chest, desired to possess them.** Generated next was the pārijāta
>   flower, which decorates the celestial planets. O King, as you fulfill
>   the desires of everyone on this planet by fulfilling all ambitions,
>   the pārijāta fulfills the desires of everyone.[Shreemad Bhagvatam](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/8/6)

According to various legends -:

Kausthubha Mani (Gem , Jewel) (कौस्तुभ मणी) is a very precious jewel came  out "Samudra Manthan"  or The churning of the Ocean of milk  by Devatas & Asuras.
 This Jewel is worn by **"Lord Vishnu" (भगवान विष्णू)**
On his chest.

"Kausthubha Mani" is **very bright jewel**
This "Kausthubha Mani"  is said to be **having no hole or defect in it. And also no string attached to it** Because "lord Vishnu" , does not like any defect or string ( String word which is used here as to denote non bondage to anything).

It is believed that where this Kausthubha Mani rests , no calamity occures there.
In another belief this jewel is representation of Lord Vishnu's brightness as Sun.