# Which is an alternative deity that destroys obstacles?

Tags: gods

There is another deity besides Ganesha who destroys obstacles. He has a big mask for a face. He is more direct then Ganesha. I forget his name, does some one know who he is?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Do you have any more information on this god? A picture would be helpful.

Comment: Lord Ganapaty is the lord of obstacles.So if he does not want ur obstacle to be removed none in the 3 worlds can remove it.

Answer (score 2):

**Lord Maha Vishnu** is also worshiped for removing obstacles from our lives. As this beautiful sanskrit shloka describes -

> **शुक्लाम्बरधरं विष्णुं शशिवर्णं चतुर्भुजम् ।**
>
> **प्रसन्नवदनं ध्यायेत् सर्वविघ्नोपशान्तये ॥**
>
> Shukla-Ambara-Dharam Vissnnum Shashi-Varnnam Catur-Bhujam |
>   Prasanna-Vadanam Dhyaayet Sarva-Vighno[a-U]pashaantaye ||
>
> Meaning: 1: (We Meditate on Sri Vishnu) Who is Wearing White Clothes,
>   Who is All-Pervading, Who isBright in Appearance like the Moon and Who
>   is Having Four Hands, 2: Who is Having a Compassionate and Gracious
>   Face, Let us Meditate on Him To **Ward of all Obstacles.**

Source -[Maha Shree Vishnu Shloka](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_vishnu-shuklambaradharam_vishnum.php)

Comment: There's lots of controversy as to who that verse is addressed to.  Some people think it's Ganesha, others think it's Vishnu, and still others think it's Vishnu's general Vishvaksena.  In any case, you're certainly correct that Vishnu is capable of removing all obstacles.

Comment: But regardless I don't think Vishnu is the god that the OP had in mind, because he said the god "has a big mask for a face".

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan -  ok , I will try to give answer in OP point of view. Will search about the deity  having mask. :)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - If necessary pls. Convert answer as comment ,whatever you think the best. Because I have missed Mask part somehow.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar see Tezz's answer [Why is the Sloka "Suklambaradharam Vishnum..." used as Ganapaty Dhyanam when it is clearly a Dhyana Sloka for Lord Vishnu?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10732/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer -Thanks for the link.

Comment: it not shiva. he looks like this http://imgur.com/a/QZqsA without the club. it similar but not exact.

Comment: @LeeBar - Check this image , its a image of a  man holding a mask  in hands. The mask is a face of Ganesha (Obstacle Removing God In Hinduism). The image is from play performed in Kokan region of India called "Dashavatara" play. You might be refering to Lord Ganesha  itself and possibly no other deity http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_vYkkkdoBWqE/ShKYsYkypWI/AAAAAAAABCo/zjth12jyMsk/s1600-h/19.JPG