# To whom does the sloka "Shuklam Baradharam Vishnum, Shashi Varnam Chaturbhujam" refer?

Tags: vishnu, identification-request, ganesha, shloka

Does the sloka mean Lord Vishnu or Ganesh ji?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the Sloka "Suklambaradharam Vishnum..." used as Ganapaty Dhyanam when it is clearly a Dhyana Sloka for Lord Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10732/why-is-the-sloka-suklambaradharam-vishnum-used-as-ganapaty-dhyanam-when-it)

Answer (score 1):

> Sukla-Ambara-Dharam Vissnnum Shashi-Varnnam Catur-Bhujam |
> Prasanna-Vadanam Dhyaayet Sarva-Vighno[a-U]pashaantaye ||

Meaning -

> We Meditate upon the God Who is Wearing White Clothes, Who is All-Pervading, Who is Bright in Appearance like the Moon and Who is Having Four Hands,
> Who is Having a Compassionate and Gracious Face, Let us Meditate on Him To Ward of all Obstacles.

Now this meaning doesn't give the name of the God for whom this sloka is devoted, but we could infer some facts from this sloka

This sloka mentions that the God has four hands ( Chaturbhujam ) which is an attribute associated with Lord Vishnu, Even Ganesh is seen with 4 hands
The color of the God is mentioned to be the color of the moon which is not generally attributed to Lord Vishnu. He is generally dark blackish blue, he is called Shyama or Krishna which is the color of sky, Ganesh is attributed the color of red

"Vishnum" in the sloka shows the omnipresence of the Lord; Both Narayana and Vishnu is omnipresent

This sloka also mentions to ward off obstacles, which both Ganesh and Vishnu are capable of doing

This sloka is also attributed to Visvaksena, who is worshipped before any ritual in Sri Vaishnavism

You can also go through a similar questions asked

- [Why is the Sloka "Suklambaradharam Vishnum..." used as Ganapaty Dhyanam when it is clearly a Dhyana Sloka for Lord Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10732/why-is-the-sloka-suklambaradharam-vishnum-used-as-ganapaty-dhyanam-when-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Whoever this sloka is devoted to, I am sure that reciting it with devotion is sure to ward off the obstacles :-)

Comment: "Vishnum" does sound like a very clear indication of the name 

Comment: Yes, I did think of it, But I wasn't sure of the Sanskrit meaning of "Vishnum" in that sloka @Surya , If you are sure of it you are free to edit and add it :-)

Comment: Of course, obviously,  it refers to Vishnu!! Who else but Vishnu? There is no other. Everything is that Paramatman. Vishnum means 'sarva vyapi' The Great Wide..Lord of Space. 'Avyaktam Sashwatham Vishnum Anantham ajamavyayam' meaning.... 'The one that is unmanifest is Vishnum..& Infinite 
 & without change'  'sarvarūpasthaṁ sarvēśaṁ' - 'All forms are Vishnu( including of course Ganesha)  and ' God of all'. All from 'Vishnu Shatamana stotram'.

Comment: Yeah @GopalAnantharaman :-)